# Where do I put activity elements in Android?

Tags: android

I'm looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

And it has a whole bunch of things that I can implement. I'm just curious if I can put these inside an `<application>` or they have to be inside of an `<activity>`. Lastly, if I wanted to use something like `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` would I need to put that inside of every single `<activity>` in my manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Consider two levels:
Application and Activity.

First of all, both tags have separate attributes , and can't be used with each other.

Secondly, think in a wider perspective that what methods(parameters) should be for application level and what for activity level.

like 
the application tag has "allowtaskreparenting" attribute.
Its explanation is, "Specify that an activity can be moved out of a task it is in to the 
 task it has an affinity for when appropriate"
It means that it is applicable for all the activities.

Similarly, if you add an attribute for the activity tag , it would just be applicable to that activity not the entire application.

I hope you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you will look at the application page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

you will see the parameters that applicable to the application tag.

those of the activity may not be applied to application.

Comment: Okay, that makes a little bit of sense. So if I wanted to `clearTaskOnLaunch` I would have to insert it into every single activity tag in my app?